# Possible to delay email sending in Jenkins?

Tags: email, jenkins

Due to high network traffic during the day, many of our Jenkins builds must run in evenings and during the night. Emails are sent containing reports, notifications of broken builds, etc. However, I don't want the emails to be sent to developers in evenings and during the night. Is it possible to queue all the emails and send them e.g. between 8-17 office hours? So if a build breaks during the night, an email is sent at 8am.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no plugin that allows to delay email sending. However, maybe you can give a try to the script capability of the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). It allows you to use JS or Groovy scripts in the template. In such script, you may write a loop that "waits" 8am to send the email.

But personnally, I don't like that idea, it's not really a good way to achieve that, and in addition it will certainly make the final result of the build wait until 8am (the build will only finish once the mail is effectively sent). This will also have the drawback that the job will take one place in the Jenkins job queue, potentially blocking another job...

Maybe developing your own plugin (by forking mail-ext plugin for example) would be a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

Let me spread my ideas.

I'm also not aware of any existing functionality to achieve that via Jenkins.
Plugin would be probably the best way (possibly beneficial for others is published to public).

The alternative solution coming to my mind is in case you are in a situation, where you have control of the e-mail server, that might also be place to achieve your goal.

As for the SMTP (based on the sever you use) there might be a solution.
Possibly solution provided here (sendmail in queue-only mode) could help you:

[How can I delay mail delivery through an SMTP relay, possibly sendmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835743/how-can-i-delay-mail-delivery-through-an-smtp-relay-possibly-sendmail)

Comment: We are using an external SMTP server, I don't think we can change the settings for it.

Comment: well, doesn't seem like a way to go for your case then :)